# Javascript Complex graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I was trying to find a special type graph for my project.

It's something similar to the sun :) I tried libraries like highchart and canvas but with this, this is not possible. You can see the design in the below link

[image: Graph modal]

If somebody has some idea please let me know. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something similar in Highcharts using `gauge` chart (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.gauge). I have prepared a demo for you, which can be found below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.gauge.dial
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.gauge.pivot

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n0z73Lp3/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the demo but, the each point have a percentage in it. did you see the image? if you look each bar you can see the color difference.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I updated my previous demo and added 'sunrays' to the chart. You just need to add as many series with a single value as number of rays you want to display. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/e48bqL60/.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the library `d3`. See an implementation of something similar [here](https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/8aaef92e64007f882267).

Comment: So how can I increase the middle radius and the bars in a rectangular form?